# C# SharpDX compilefromfile with embedded resource

Tags: c#, sharpdx

Hello I have few files which are now embedded resources, but problem is using:

```
CompilationResult result = SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(
            fileName,
            entryPoint,
            profile,
            shaderFlags,
            include: FileIncludeHandler.Default,
            defines: defines);
```

Put error:
`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Unable to find file'`. I found that there is other function which Compiles from source:

```
CompilationResult result = SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderBytecode.Compile(data,profile,shaderFlags);
```

To read from embedded resource file I using this little class: [Link 1](http://www.vcskicks.com/embedded-resource.php)

Usage looks like this:

```
string data = ResourceHelper.GetEmbeddedResource(fileName);
CompilationResult result = SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderBytecode.Compile(data,profile,shaderFlags);
```

But now I get this error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entryPoint'
```

To check if app loads all embeded resource I used this small method and it returns all embedded resources

```
string[] zz = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", zz));
```

What I'm missing here?

Edit 1:

This is full method of how I use it:

```
public static ShaderBytecode CompileShader(string fileName, string entryPoint, string profile, ShaderMacro[] defines = null)
    {
        var shaderFlags = ShaderFlags.None;
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fileName))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                CompilationResult result = SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderBytecode.Compile(reader.ReadToEnd(),entrypoint,profile,shaderFlags);

                /*CompilationResult result = SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(
                    fileName,
                    entryPoint,
                    profile,
                    shaderFlags,
                    include: FileIncludeHandler.Default,
                    defines: defines);*/
                return new ShaderBytecode(result);
            }
        }    
    }
```

Real Usage:

```
string MainName = "my_project";
_shaders["standardVS"] = D3DUtility.CompileShader(MainName+".Shaders.Default.hlsl", "VS", "vs_5_1");
//50 other files...
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy6cN.png)

EDIT 2: Added entrypoint to Compile method, but now it throws error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

In:

```
return new ShaderBytecode(result);
```

Execption handler shows this:

```
Message="C\FileLocation: error X1505: No include handler specified, can't perform a #include. Use D3DX APIs or provide your own include handler.\n"
```

EDIT 3: Using @J. van Langen updated method it shows like this:

```
System.Exception: 'C:\Users\test\source\repos\myapp\Debug\Resources\DemoScene\unknown(14,10-30): error X1505: No include handler specified, can't perform a #include. Use D3DX APIs or provide your own include handler.'

result.Message = result.Message="error CS0452: The type 'ShaderBytecode' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'CompilationResultBase<T>'"
```

EDIT 4: I think I found why its throwing error since it has include inside it:
 [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/k3AKL84f)

Comment: It seems that your shader code isn't correct. See my update how to capture that

Comment: Done see my updated error in Edit 3

Comment: See my Edit 4 I think I found why its throwing error

Comment: Looks like `#include` doesn't work. I don't know an alternative for that.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `CompileFromFile` but just `Compile` also, you need the overload with the `Compile(string shaderSource, string entryPoint, string profile, ShaderFlags shaderFlags, .....` the rest of the parameters uses default.

Here's an example from an old project i've done:

```
static GradientRenderer()
{
    // This may be changed to GetType()   (see 'The new reflection API')
    var assembly = typeof(GradientRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

    //string[] resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

    string code;

    // use the full filename with namespace
    using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MirageDX11.Renderers.Gradient.Gradient.hlsl"))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        // read the whole content to a string.
        code = reader.ReadToEnd();

    var shaderFlags = ShaderFlags.None;

#if DEBUG
    shaderFlags |= ShaderFlags.Debug;
    shaderFlags |= ShaderFlags.SkipOptimization;
#endif

    // Compile the vertex shader and the pixel shader  "VS" & "PS" => entrypoint
    _vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.Compile(code, "VS", "vs_5_0", shaderFlags);
    _pixelShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.Compile(code, "PS", "ps_5_0", shaderFlags);
}
```

---

Here's the shader

```
struct VertexIn
{
    float3 PosL : POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

struct VertexOut
{
    float4 PosH : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color: COLOR;
};

VertexOut VS(VertexIn vin)
{
    VertexOut vout;
    vout.PosH = float4(vin.PosL, 1.0f);
    vout.Color = vin.Color;
    return vout;
}

float4 PS(VertexOut pin) : SV_Target
{
    float4 value = pin.Color;
    value.w = 1.0f;
    return value;
}
```

---

Update about how to capture shader errors:

I've modified your method to capture the shader compile errors. It will raise an exception with a useful message.

```
public static ShaderBytecode CompileShader(string fileName, string entryPoint, string profile, ShaderMacro[] defines = null)
{
    var shaderFlags = ShaderFlags.None;
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fileName))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            CompilationResult result = SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderBytecode.Compile(reader.ReadToEnd(),entrypoint,profile,shaderFlags);

            // when the Bytecode == null, means that an error has occurred
            if (result.Bytecode == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(result.Message);

            // removed old code in comment...

            return new ShaderBytecode(result);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: I added mine usage, it very similar to yours.

Comment: @speed258 
 Your function accepts the entrypoint, but the compile function doesn't get the entrypoint parameter as argument ... `SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderBytecode.Compile(reader.ReadToEnd(), <<HERE>>, profile,shaderFlags);` you're missing the entrypoint.. The name of the function..